# disable or remove caching images in Inertiajs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs

In my Inertiajs app when uploading and replacing a image like `header.png` links never changes so Inertia when visiting another Inertia page and going back `header.png` is never changed but when I reloading the page it works and shows newly updated image.

I used this code but didn't worked.

```
const updateHeader = ()=> {
    form.post(route('header.update'), {
        onSuccess () {
            Inertia.reload({
                only: revalidate_on_popstate_data,
                preserveState: false,
                preserveScroll: true,
                replace: true
            });
        }
    });
}
```